# Why do I need a minimum of 100 GB free disk space just to build the Android project source code?

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, diskspace

Why do I need a minimum of 100 GB free disk space only to "checkout" the Android project source code and over 150 GB just to build it?

https://source.android.com/source/requirements.html

When a buy a new Android phone with let's say 32 GB memory, only about 8 GB of those 32 GB are used before I get to install apps and that. I still have almost 25 GB space left!

Why does the Android source code take up more than 150 GB when it's build on a computer but only about 8 GB when it's build on a phone?

Thanks, sincerely

Comment: Checking out a project from version control, and building a project (regardless of where you build it) are completely different things. You cannot possible expect the project + its entire history and the compiled build to take up the same amount of space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Checking out a project from version control, and building a project [...] are completely different things. You cannot [...] expect the project [plus] its entire history and the compiled build to take up the same amount of space" - @Tim Castelijns

Comment: A normal way of handling such a case is to ask @Tim Castelijns to post the useful comment as answer which you could accept later on.